# How to backup Windows 7 Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, photos, sql-server

How do I backup Windows Live Photo Gallery?

I've been running on Windows 7 RC and I want to upgrade to the full Windows 7 release.

I've been managing my photos with Live Photo Gallery. I want to back this up in case I need to do a full reinstall while doing the upgrade.

I realise that it uses SQL Server 2005 CE. Do I need to back up this database with some database specific tools?

Or is there a way to export all the data so that it can be reimported at a later date (all my photos are on a data drive which won't be overwritten by any reinstall of the OS).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the database to a backup directory:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Photo Gallery\" "C:\Backups\Windows Live Photo Gallery" Pictures.pd4
```